# Cómo hacer un upsample en undataframe para el aprendizaje automático?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data, machine-learning, dataframe

Tengo un problema de clasificación multiclase. Se desempeña bastante bien, pero en las clases menos representadas no lo hace. De hecho, aquí está la distribución:

[image]

Y aquí están los resultados de mi clasificación anterior (saqué los números de las etiquetas):

[image].

Por lo tanto, traté de mejorar la clasificación reduciendo el muestreo de las clases mayoritarias.

```
import os
from sklearn.utils import resample

# rebalance data
#df = resample_data(df)

if True:

    count_class_A, count_class_B,count_class_C, count_class_D,count_class_E, count_class_F, count_class_G = df.grade.value_counts()
    count_df = df.shape[0] 
    class_dict = {"A": count_class_A,"B" :count_class_B,"C": count_class_C,"D": count_class_D,"E": count_class_E, "F": count_class_F, "G": count_class_G}
    counts = [count_class_A, count_class_B,count_class_C, count_class_D,count_class_E, count_class_F, count_class_G]
    median = statistics.median(counts)


    for key in class_dict:
        if class_dict[key]>median:
            print(key)
            df[df.grade == key] = df[df.grade == key].sample(int(count_df/7), replace = False) 
                                             #replace=False,    # sample without replacement
                                             #n_samples=int(count_df/7),     # to match minority class
                                             #random_state=123)
# Divide the data set into training and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = split_data(df, APPLICANT_NUMERIC + CREDIT_NUMERIC,
                  APPLICANT_CATEGORICAL,
                  TARGET,
                  test_size = 0.2,
                  #row_limit = os.environ.get("sample"))
                  row_limit = 552160)
```

Sin embargo, los resultados fueron catastróficos. La precisión del modelo y la pérdida del modelo parecían tener algunos problemas :

[image]

Y todo estaba clasificado en "A" en el set de pruebas.